# Git working with patches

Tags: git, version-control, patch

To follow up on my previous question [Git work flow with an inexpirenced member.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949266/git-work-flow-with-an-inexpirenced-member)
I choose to have him send patches to me. The problem is i haven't used patches before and i can't find tutorials giving explanation on the work flow.

What i want is have him pull the latest code from the repo. create a branch work on it commit his changes when he is done i want him to create a patch for it so i can integrate it into master.

Can you tell me how can i create patches in a situation like this and apply it to my master?

Answer (score 4):

Create patch with [git-format-patch(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-format-patch.html), or, if you want to send emails just [git-send-email(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-send-email.html).

Then apply it with [git-apply(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html) or, for email, [git-am(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html).

Answer (score 2):

That's relatively easy. Say the branch is foo, and the patches from master:

```
# Put every patch for revisions from master to foo into tmp: 0001, 0002, etc...
git format-patch master...foo --stdout > yo

....

# You apply the patches with git am
cat yo | git am
```

Note that it won't give you the same revisions as the original because of commiters differences. That's a bit more complicated in that case (http://home.regit.org/?page_id=32)

Answer (score 1):

without commiting:

```
git pull
<hack>
git diff -p > myfirstpatch.txt
```

then he can email you the patch.

if he does commit, then just give diff some arguments.

```
git diff blah...blah2 -p >mysecondpatch.txt
```

then you just do:

```
git apply mysecondpatch.txt
```